# onClick attribute data show

Tags: javascript, onclick, attributes

I would like to show a periodic table data on a single div by using onClick event and get data from li attribute itself.

**JavaScrip code:**

```
<script>
    function myElement() {

        var number = document.getElementById("myBtn").getAttribute("data-number");
        var symbol = document.getElementById("myBtn").getAttribute("data-symbol");
        var name = document.getElementById("myBtn").getAttribute("data-name");
        var mass = document.getElementById("myBtn").getAttribute("data-mass");

        document.getElementById("element-info").innerHTML = '<span class="atomic-number">' + number + '</span>' + '<h1>' + symbol + '</h1>' + '<p>' + name + '</p>' + '<p>' + mass + '</p>';
    }

</script>
```

**You can see the HTML code below:**

```
enter code here
```

you can see in the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sWJw.png)

If any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: You are missing the JS code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

You can check this:

```
<ul>
<li id="option1" 
   data-id="101" 
   data-option="21"
   onclick="goDoSomething(this);">
       Option-1
</li>
<li id="option1" 
   data-id="102" 
   data-option="22" 
   onclick="goDoSomething(this);">
       Option-2
</li>
```

JS Code:

```
function goDoSomething(d){
var dataOption = (d.getAttribute("data-option"));
var dataId = (d.getAttribute("data-id"));

document.getElementById("outPut").innerHTML = 
'<p>' + 'Data Option:' + dataOption + '</p>' + 
'<p>' + 'Data Id:' + dataId + '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? I invented the HTML, since is missing from your question.

```js
function myElement() {
        var number = myBtn.dataset.number;
        var symbol = myBtn.dataset.symbol;
        var name = myBtn.dataset.name;
        var mass = myBtn.dataset.mass;

        document.getElementById("element_info").innerHTML = '<span class="atomic-number">' + number + '</span>' + '<h1>' + symbol + '</h1>' + '<p>' + name + '</p>' + '<p>' + mass + '</p>';
    }


myBtn.addEventListener("click", myElement)
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" data-number="1" data-symbol="symbol" data-name="name" data-mass="mass">my button</button>

<p id="element_info"></p>
```

Comment: <li class="hydrogen" id="myBtn" onClick="myElement()" data-name="Hydrogen" data-symbol="H" data-number="1" data-mass="1.008">
            <abbr title="Hydrogen">H</abbr>
            <span class="atomic-number">1</span>
        </li>